# jQuery. Click HTML button to get clicked Facebook like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, button, facebook-like

I have 2 buttons, 1 simple and other Facebook like button, I want to make that after my simple button is clicked, It activated(clicked) Facebook button too, but It wont work. I've used this code:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#test").click(function(){
             $("#fb-root").click(); //this doesn't click Like button
             alert("Like is clicked"); // this alert when button is clicked
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/myPage" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" ></div>

<input type="button" id="test" name="test" value="Test" />
```

This is other code.After my Like button is clicked It alert "I just clicked like button", but this line not working `$(this).remove();`. (But I need to make like I said in first case. Click "Test" button to get clicked "fb-like" button.)

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(e) {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
             $(this).remove(); // I used this to remove button after clicking, but not working
             alert('I just clicked like button');
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Maybe some lines from this code are needed, something like these `window.fbAsyncInit = function(e) {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {`?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you won't be able to click the Facebook like button this way.

This is a security limitation in place to prevent you from clicking anything on a third party site that you don't want to. Here's more information about [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) and the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).