# jQuery. How to remove button after It is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, button, facebook-like

How to remove Facebook like button after It is clicked (with jQuery)?

This is my code. After Like button is clicked It alert "I just clicked like button", but this line not working `$(this).remove();`. How to remove It?

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(e) {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
             $(this).remove(); // I used this to remove button after clicking, but not working
             alert('I just clicked like button');
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

And this is my FB Like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/myPage" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" ></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$(this).remove()` with

```
$( ".fb-like" ).remove();
```

It will remove the element with the `fb-like` class.

Comment: Thank you for answer, that worked, but why It removing and alert text only after 3 seconds, not instant?

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė  I think's it's connecting to the Facebook server and checking if you subscribed, I'd say it's normal.  Also, if it worked, please accept my answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Maybe do you know why this doesn't work? 
`<script>
$(function(){
    $("#filter").click(function(e){
         $( ".fb-like" ).click();
   alert("Like is clicked");
    });
});
</script>` This is other button, which after clicking should use fb like button? Here is explained in other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765539/jquery-click-html-button-to-get-clicked-facebook-like-button

Comment: This works but what if the OP has 2 .fb-like buttons? You should use $(event.target.id).remove();